# App crashes in iPad IOS 5.0.1

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios5, crash, three20

I have an application which has Three20 framework.  It is working perfectly in iPad IOS 5.0 and iOS4.3.  However, our customers says that the app crashes while logging in to the application itself. Because after login it has a three20 framework.  I am not sure where the problem exists.   Please guide me.  Is there any way I can test the app for IOS 5.0.1 with the simulator?

Any help is greatly appreciated...

Comment: If you can't duplicate the problem or show crash logs, then we can't help you.

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The problem is I cant reproduce the problem..  I dont have a device with IOS 5.0.1.  That is the problem.  I checked for crash reports in apple account.  I dont have that in itunesconnect also.

Comment: CodaFi is right. Is there no way to replicate it on an actual device with iOS 5.0.1? Otherwise, you might ask one or some of your customers to send in their crash reports. They are synced to their computers see http://aplus.rs/apple/how-to-find-crash-logs-for-iphone-applications-on-mac-vista-and-xp/

Comment: What keeps you from updating one of your devices to iOS 5.0.1?

Comment: It is my companies device I have to go through a long process to update my IOS.  If I cant identify I have to do it.

Comment: Is there any way I can test the app in IOS5.0.1 simulator.

Comment: Thank you all for guiding me..  I will try to get the log as soon as possible ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install a crash handler. We use BugSense (free): http://bugsense.com 
Make sure you follow their guidelines, in return you will get a detailed crash report from every device that crashed with the specific address of the crash.

With the archive file in place you should run the atos command to resolve that address to a line number like this:
cd into [ArchiveName].xcarchive/Products/Applications
and then run 
atos -o [appname].app/[appname] -arch armv7 [address]

it will resolve to the line number which should get you started.

if you are sending an adhoc build to customers I suggest you use the Testflight SDK http://testflightapp.com . it also installs a crash handler + it allows you to upload the symbol files (.dsym) and they do the resolve for you.

Comment: Hay thanks for your help..  I have used TestFlight SDK for testfilght builds.  I hope I cant use this while submitting to appstore.  What about BugSenese.  Can I use it for submitting to appsotre.

Comment: Testflight should be used only on AdHoc builds. you can ifdef the includes and the code to initialize it. Bugsense shuold be used for the build you're uploading to the appstore.